# Bijection on finite fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I am trying to solve a problem about bijections on finite fields, but I am stuck on this problem and don't see how can I solve it. So, here it is:

Given is a polynomial $g(y):=y^{3}+3y^{2}+3y+3\in \mathbb{Z}[y]$. Show that it defines a bijection from $\mathbb{F}_{11^{31415}}$ to itself.

To show the bijection $\mathbb{F}_{11^{31415}}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{11^{31415}}$, I've been thinking that I have to find an inverse map, but I don't know how to do it. I think this should be better than proving that the map is injective and surjective. I also noticed that this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ and that the number $31415=5\times 61\times 103$, but I don't know what that brings to the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Observe that $g(y)=(y+1)^3+2$, so its inverse is *something like* $g^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x-2}\,-1$.

The only problematic part is the cubic root, so all you shoud show is that $x\mapsto x^3$ is a bijection in the given field. Since that is finite, its multiplicative group is cyclic, of order $11^{31415}-1$.

Since we have $11\equiv -1 \pmod3$, $\ 11^{31415}\equiv -1\pmod{3}$, so that the group order is coprime to $3$, and therefore $x\mapsto x^3$ is indeed a bijection:

By the Bezout identity, there are integers $a,b$ such that $a\cdot N+b\cdot 3=1$ where $N$ denotes the order of the group now. So that $x\mapsto x^b$ will be an inverse for $x\mapsto x^3$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Only the last part of your proof is not clear for me...computation is okay, but how does the bijection follow from the group order coprime to 3?

Comment: Before the edit, i've beet thinking that you're using this theorem: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Kth_power_map_is_bijective_iff_k_is_relatively_prime_to_the_order

Comment: Yes, it is just that one.